# How to make Incoming SMS via Twilio Appear and Generate Notifications in Bitrix

Tags: twilio, bitrix

Hi I've integrated Twilio with Bitrix and am able to send outgoing sms that do reach the receiving number, but the incoming reply texts do not appear on the contact profile or generate notifications.  To summarize, I need help making incoming sms appear in contact profiles and generate notifications for all/most employees.

I heard one method was to use Bitrix24 webhook for authorization and API REST for data. If this method works then I need a step-by-step on how to do it.

I have limited coding experience.

---

I've tried generating a Bitrix webhook and setting that as the incoming URL for the text messages in Twilio but the replies still did not appear.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is how to create webhooks in Bitrix https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/rest_sum/webhooks.php .. If you have any questions about some `code` examples, please, feel free and ask them to us.